# Update counts according to a label

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
>      data have;
>      input ID :$20. Label :$20. Hours :$20. Days :$20.;
>      cards;
>      0001 w  3144  3
>      0001 w  23    54
>      0001 p  12    1
>      0002 m  456   34
>      0002 w  2     1
>      0002 s  231   45
>      0002 w  98    23
>      0003 w  12    6
>      0003 w  98    76
>       ;
> ```

Is there a way to, for each ID, sum the Hours, so get the total and then split it by the days but only when the label is == w? If the label is not w put a missing.

Desired output:

> ```
>      data have;
>      input ID :$20. Label :$20. Hours :$20. Days :$20.;
>      cards;
>      0001 w  167.3158  3
>      0001 w  3011.684  54
>      0001 p    .       1
>      0002 m    .       34
>      0002 w  32.79167  1
>      0002 s    .       45
>      0002 w  754.2084  23
>      0003 w  8.048778  6
>      0003 w  101.9512  76
>       ;
> ```

In other words: for 0001 in the desired output example I added: 3144+23+12 = 3179, the 54+3=57 that are the days where the label is "w" then I divided 3179 by 57 and multiplied the result for 3 and 54 but not for 1 respectively.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same idea with @Stu Sztukowski, but use DOW-Loop skill:

```
data want;
  do until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id notsorted;
    sum_of_hours=sum(sum_of_hours,input(hours,best.));
    sum_of_days_w=sum(sum_of_days_w,(label='w')*input(days,best.));
  end;
  do until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id notsorted;
    if label='w' then hours=cats(sum_of_hours*(input(days,best.)/sum_of_days_w));
    else hours='';
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The calculation you need to do looks like this in code form:

```
if(id = 'w') then hours = sum_of_hours_w/sum_of_days * days
    else hours = .
```

All we need to do is get the sum of hours and days where `label = 'w'`, then merge it back with our original table by `id`. The table to do this calculation would look like this:

| id | label | hours | days | sum_of_hours | sum_of_days_w |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | w | 3144 | 3 | 3179 | 57 |
| 0001 | w | 23 | 54 | 3179 | 57 |

You can accomplish this all in a single SQL step.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select t1.id
             , t1.label
             , CASE(t1.label)
                   when('w') then t2.sum_hours/t2.sum_days_w * t1.days
                   else .
               END as hours
             , t1.days
        from have as t1

        /* Get the sum of all hours and days where label = 'w' */
        LEFT JOIN
            (select id
                  , sum( (label = 'w')*days ) as sum_days_w
                  , sum(hours) as sum_hours
             from have
             group by id
            ) as t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately I need to retain also the cases where the label is not "w".

Comment: This code retains those cases but set the hours to missing based on your desired output. The order differs since a SQL merge is performed, but you can reorder it with an `order by` clause.